# Treat missing values as zero in SAS where clause

Tags: sas

Is there an equivalent of the Oracle NVL function in SAS?

For example, if I have a where clause in SAS that says:

```
where myVar > -2;
```

it is not going to include any rows that have myVar = .

If I want to treat missing values as zero, i have to say:

```
where myVar > -2 or missing( myVar )
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
where NVL( myVar, 0 ) > -2 // or some SAS equivalent
```

Is there something like this in SAS?

Comment: Note that it's only in non-SAS data that rows with myVar=. won't be included. The reason is that missing values are NULL, and comparisons with NULL will always evaluate to FALSE.
In native SAS data, missing values are treated as a non-negative number, which is less than zero.
So "where myVar > -2;" will actually work with missing values when operating on native SAS data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [coalesce function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/61724/HTML/default/a002518172.htm) should do the job.

```
where coalesce(myVar,0) > -2
```

I'm not sure if the function became available in SAS 9, so if you have a really old SAS version this might not work.

Answer (score 7):

Using the coalesce function is the right way to do this.

But if you have an old version of SAS where coalesce isn't implemented, you can use this trick:

```
where sum(myVar,0) > -2
```

If you use the [sum function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/61724/HTML/default/a000245953.htm) in SAS for adding, any non-missing number in the summation will force the result to be non-missing.

Thus adding 0 with the sum function will transform a missing value to 0, and non-missing values will remain unaltered.

Comment: +1: That's an awesome suggestion! We no longer support SAS 8 for our product so I really dont care if coalesce was available then or not but if I did, this would be an ingenious workaround.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that y can do is 
like 
array varlistname var1 var2 var3 varn;
if array <>. then output;

It will ouput data sets having non missing values